# How to push menu content down when hamburger icon is clicked?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want my hamburger icon to push down the content, meaning the background and writing when the hamburger icon is clicked on. I tried to add padding to the body and set the width to the hamburger but does not seem to be working. I have been trying for the last couple hours. I only want to use CSS if possible.

```css
.mobile-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
  background: var(--bg-color);
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 2;
}

.mobile-nav .menu {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: none;
}

.mobile-nav .menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0.1rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.mobile-nav #toggle {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-nav #toggle:checked + .menu {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-nav">
    <label for="toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#promise">OUR PROMISE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team">TEAM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sponsors">SPONSORSHIPS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your main content in a div and adjust the top margin when the menu is expanded.

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-sw6stx)

HTML:

```
<body id="body">
    <div class="mobile-nav">
        <label for="toggle">button</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" onclick='onClickHandler(this)'>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#promise">OUR PROMISE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team">TEAM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sponsors">SPONSORSHIPS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    Content
  </div>
</body>

<script>
function onClickHandler(e){
  var content = document.getElementById("body");

  if(e.checked){
     content.setAttribute( 'class', 'push-down' );

  }else{
     content.setAttribute( 'class', '' );
  }
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
//.. your styles 

#content{
  height:300px;
  background-color:yellow;
  margin-top:50px;
}

#body.push-down{
  margin-top:250px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment the syntax is now pushing down the writing on my website but would also like the background to push down the content I had a mess about with the code you suggested and I am not able to achieve this atm myself is this possible to do?

Comment: Try pushing down the body rather than a content div. see my updated answer.

Comment: Still no luck now the content is not pushing down what so ever

Answer (score 0):

You may use **max-height: 0px;** and **overflow: hidden;** instead of **display: none;** for div.menu . Animate max-height: on toggle.

**js for toggle class**

```
$('#toggle').on('click', function(){
    $('.mobile-nav .menu').toggleClass('active'); //Toggle Class on Click
});
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
.menu.active {
    max-height: 500px; //Set any value higher than menu
}
```

See a **working demo here :**  https://jsfiddle.net/rbzfk0ca/36/